# php html5 video pseduo stream with php proxy

Tags: php, stream, html5-video

I can seek any point of video with jw player. But i cant seek videos with html5. I defined all varriables on my php script. But note that i am using proxy to stream videos. Here is my video which streams with proxy:
http://cdn7.ceay.biz/test/kndjhjdojdjfoo.mp4

And here is my php script:

```
@set_time_limit(0);
header('Content-type: video/mp4');

include('curl.php');

$vkurl = 'http://somesite.com/video.mp4'
$stream = $_GET['start'];
$curl = new Curl(time());

$curl->stream("$vkurl?start=$stream");
```

Comment: Why are you using `?start=`?  Why not just let the range requests occur on their own?

Comment: Because it uses ?start for streaming.

Comment: The browser won't do this natively for your HTML5 streams.  You aren't passing all of the request headers to the page you are proxying to.

Comment: So it is impossible or can someone fix this code for me?

Comment: First off, nobody here is going to fix anything for you.  We'll teach you what you're doing wrong, and you fix the code yourself.  Now, of course this isn't impossible, but you seem to be adamant that you are using this `start` parameter in the query string.  I'm trying to explain to you that this is unusual, and that I am skeptical that this parameter is needed.  Use Fiddler or Wireshark to verify the request data.  You probably don't need this parameter, and probably just need to relay all of the request/response headers in both directions.